# Binding UserControls DependencyProperty to ViewModels Property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, command, dependency-properties

I am having a UserControl called `ChartControl` which displays a chart. To determine that the `ChartControl` is initialized, it needs to run a command which is defined inside a ViewModel called `DiagnosisViewModel`. The Command gets instantiated inside this ViewModel. After the `ChartControl` is loaded, it should execute the Command, but at this point, it is still null. It seems like that the Binding of the Command does not work as expected. Let the explain it better with code:

`ChartControl.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="GoBeyond.Ui.Controls.Charts.ChartControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="ThisChartControl"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
</UserControl>
```

`ChartControl.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class ChartControl : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ChartControl()
    {
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ReadyCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ReadyCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(ChartControl), new PropertyMetadata((o, args) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Ready Command updated");
            }));

    public ICommand ReadyCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ReadyCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ReadyCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the ChartControl with some values
        ...

        // At this point the Command is ALWAYS null
        ReadyCommand?.Execute(this);
    }
}
```

`ChartControl defined in DiagnosisView.xaml`

```
<charts:ChartControl ReadyCommand="{Binding FrequencyReadyCommand}" />
```

`DiagnosisViewModel`

```
public class DiagnosisViewModel : ViewModelBase // ViewModelBase derives from Prisms BindableBase
{
    public DiagnosisViewModel(...)
    {
        FrequencyReadyCommand = new DelegateCommand<ChartControl>(OnFrequencyChartReady);
    }

    public ICommand FrequencyReadyCommand
    {
        get => _frequencyReadyCommand;
        set => SetProperty(ref _frequencyReadyCommand, value);
    }
}
```

The getter of `FrequencyReadyCommand` seems never gets called, so I think there is any issue with my binding here. I tried with multiple Modes and UpdateSourceTriggers, but I cannot find out, what I am doing wrong here

Comment: I don't see anywhere you instantiate VM nor ReadyCommand. VM is not relevant to your problem but ReadyCommand is not created anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should invoke the command in the dependency property callback instead of handling the `Loaded` event:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ReadyCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ReadyCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(ChartControl), new PropertyMetadata((o, args) =>
        {
            ChartControl chartControl = (ChartControl)o;
            chartControl.ReadyCommand?.Execute(null);
        }));
```

Unlike the `Loaded` event, the callback is always invoked *after* the property has been set.

Comment: I see, but the problem is, thet the callback never gets executed. So I think the Binding is the problem

Comment: Remove `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`. Otherwise you won't be able to bind to the view model.

Comment: Removing the DataContext line seemed to fix the issue, but I need the Loaded Event to execute, because there are some other views which must be loaded. Never the less: Thanks a lot!